# babel compiler exports undefined and the actual export together

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, babeljs

Could someone explain why babel compiles the following:

```
import {resolve} from "path";
export const exportedConst = "value";
```

to:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.exportedConst = undefined;

var _path = require("path");

var exportedConst = exports.exportedConst = "value";
```

and if I exported `exportedConst` without importing any other modules:

```
export const exportedConst = "value";
```

it compiles it to:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var exportedConst = exports.exportedConst = "value";
```

Why does it produce this line?
        exports.exportedConst = undefined;

and export it like this

```
var exportedConst = exports.exportedConst = "value";
```

this causes the IDE to see two exports

[image]

Maybe this is intelliJ problem, but it made me think about why babel does it this way.

I am using:

- nodejs          :v8.5.0
- babel-cli       : 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.0)
- babel-preset-env: 1.6.1

[Try it here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbygUwM4QDYDdkF84BmUEIcARGAIYwAWZA3AFDIAekscAxhAHaryt2MZABMAwr35wAvOSyUMAV2QNGQA&debug=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0)

or if you want to reproduce it locally, here is a quick one-line command

```
mkdir stackoverflow-questin && cd stackoverflow-questin && npm init -y && npm install babel-cli babel-preset-env && echo 'import {resolve} from "path";\nexport const exportedConst = "value";' > index.js && npx babel index.js --out-file index.compiled.js --presets=env
```

Comment: Notice, this can also be reproduced using the babel ["try it out"](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbygUwM4QDYDdkF84BmUEIcARGAIYwAWZA3AFDIAekscAxhAHaryt2MZABMAwr35wAvOSyUMAV2QNGQA&debug=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0) on the website, so its not strictly neserely to use the command line to test it (saves some time for the people who are trying to answer)

Comment: I am not sure about its intent, but it's coming from https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v6.26.0/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/src/index.js#L496-L523 Probably related to hoisting...